# Data displayed wrong when exported to excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

So I have this code:

```
import itertools
import xlsxwriter
from pprint import pprint

inputdata = [
    ['900x200', '200x500', '232x232'],
    ['242423', '232d2s', '2sdad'],
    ['AA', 'BB'],
]
result = list(itertools.product(*inputdata))
pprint(result)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Documents/files/arrays.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0

for col, data in enumerate(result):
    worksheet.write_column(row, col, data)

workbook.close()
```

First part generates combinations then it's saved to a excel file.

My issue is that items are displayed like this:
= = = = = = = =
= = = = = = = =
= = = = = = = =

And I want them to be like:
= = =
= = = 
= = = 
= = = 
= = =
= = =
= = =

Basically just "rotate" as the data doesn't make much sense currently.

Comment: Basically I need to transpose the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just not using the write function for the output you want.
Change `worksheet.write_column(row, col, data)` to `worksheet.write_row(row, col, data)`

Basically your new script should be:

```py
import itertools
import xlsxwriter
from pprint import pprint

inputdata = [
    ['900x200', '200x500', '232x232'],
    ['242423', '232d2s', '2sdad'],
    ['AA', 'BB'],
]
result = list(itertools.product(*inputdata))
pprint(result)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('arrays.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

col = 0

for row, data in enumerate(result):
    worksheet.write_row(row, col, data)

workbook.close()
```

This produces the output you want